# Nokia HERE Map using Google Latitude

Tags: geolocation, kml, here-api

I am trying to parse and add my google latitude KML marker into the Nokia HERE map.  It only works locally on my laptop in IE 9, but it doesn't add the marker in Safari 5.7, Chrome 27 (locally or on my web server).  Any ideas?

```
kml.parseKML("http://latitude.google.com/latitude/apps/badge/api?user=-1099057214648547758&type=kml");
```

Answer (score 0):

If the KML is being loaded successful on some browsers but not others, then this is almost certainly due to the browser in question kindly trying to prevent a cross-scripting domain attack.

You have **three** options

- Host the KML file in the same domain as the JavaScript reading the file - e.g. if you own `example.com`, the JavaScript should be hosted on `example.com` and the KML hosted on `example.com`
- set up the KML parser to retrieve the file `example.com`  and  use a proxy solution such as  this [php example](http://benalman.com/projects/php-simple-proxy/) to really retrieve the file from elsewhere
- Enable **CORS** on the server hosting the KML file, and load the KML using AJAX followed by the `parse()` method as shown in this [example](http://heremaps.github.io/examples/explorer.html#load-kml-file-cross-domain)

If the KML is **never** loaded successfully, you should check to see whether the file is [valid](http://feedvalidator.org/check.cgi), and indeed whether the HTML displaying the map is syntactically correct.